# rb:29: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

Trying to figure out why I'm getting this error.

Methods that have an If/Else statement don't require an end statement?

Also, somehow the formatting is all screwed up. Tried for several minutes to fix. Don't know where I went wrong?

```
def greeter(name)
  puts "Hello #{name}!!"
end

def by_three?(num)
  if num % 3 == 0
    puts true
   else
    puts false

 def age(n)   
if n < 30
    puts "You are younger than 30!"
else 
    puts "You are older than 30!" 


puts "Enter your name"
your_name = gets.chomp
puts "Enter your age"
yourage = gets.chomp


by_three?(3)
greeter(your_name)
age(your_age)
```

Comment: `if` statements always require an `end`. same with methods. seems like you're missing some...

Answer (score 2):

Both `def` and `if` should be closed with `end`:

```
def by_three?(num)
  if num % 3 == 0
    puts true
  else
    puts false
  end
end
```

Ruby methods which end with `?` should return a boolean.

Your `by_three?` just displays `true` or `false`, but returns nil.

```
by_three?(5)
# false
# => nil
```

You can remove puts :

```
def by_three?(num)
  if num % 3 == 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

puts by_three?(3)
# true
# => nil

by_three?(5)
# => false
```

But then, your if statement becomes redundant, and can also be removed :

```
def by_three?(num)
  num % 3 == 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct way of writing this is:

```
def by_three?(num)
  if num % 3 == 0
     puts true
  else
     puts false
  end # if needs an end
end #def also needs an end
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare with your version:

```
def greeter(name)
  puts "Hello #{name}!!"
end

def by_three?(num) num % 3 == 0 ? true : false end

def age(n)
  if n.to_f < 30
    puts "You are younger than 30!"
  else puts "You are older than 30!"
  end
end
```

Please notice I've added `to_f` to `n` in `age` because it will fail when left as string, since `chomp` returns string and you can't implicitly compare `string` and `integer`.

Comment: You can remove `? true : false `.